# (Mac) creating keyboard events causes memory leaks

Tags: objective-c, macos, memory, keyboard-events, cgeventtap

My app's memory usage goes up permanently, each time I create a keyboard event using Quartz Event Services.

The following is the problematic code inside of an infinite loop:

```
int keyCode = 0;
BOOL keyDownBool = FALSE;

while (TRUE) {


    /* creating a keyboard event */

    CGEventSourceRef source = CGEventSourceCreate(kCGEventSourceStatePrivate);

    CGEventRef keyboardEvent =
    CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(source, (CGKeyCode)keyCode, keyDownBool);

    CFRelease(source);
    CFRelease(keyboardEvent);



}
```

`Instruments.app` says that there are no memory leaks...

What is the problem here?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my c program not free memory as it should?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447899/why-does-my-c-program-not-free-memory-as-it-should)

Comment: The event source and the event are reusable. Create one event source if you want to send many events. Create one event i you want to send the same event over and over again.

Comment: @Willeke yep that was it. Only creating CGEventSource once and then reusing it fixes the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so the solution is pretty simple. You only need to create your `CGEventSourceRef` once, and then you can reuse it each time you want to post an event. Creating your `CGEventSourceRef`over and over again causes the "leaks" to happen.

The proper code looks like this:

```
int keyCode = 0;
BOOL keyDownBool = FALSE;


CGEventSourceRef source = CGEventSourceCreate(kCGEventSourceStatePrivate);



while (TRUE) {


    /* creating a keyboard event */


    CGEventRef keyEvent =
    CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(source, (CGKeyCode)keyCode, keyDownBool);


    CFRelease(keyEvent);



}
```

Thanks to @Willeke for the suggestion.